# How does invalidation work in AWS DynamoDB DAX multi-region

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-dax

We are using DynamoDB global tables and planning to use DAX on the top of DynamoDB to enable caching. But I don't see any mention of how DAX invalidation will take place in multi-region setup.

For example, let's say there are 2 clusters, one in us-west-2 and one in us-east-2. If we update something in us-east-2 using the DAX client it's cache will be updated but while replicating the data to us-west-2, will global table update cache in us-west-2 as well? I don't see any mention of this in the [DynamoDB documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DAX.consistency.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The DAX cache will not be updated**. Global tables will replicate the data in other regions. However, it wouldn't update the cache. Even, the `query cache` and `item cache` are independent.

> DAX does not refresh result sets in the query cache with the most
>   current data from DynamoDB. Each result set in the query cache is
>   current as of the time that the Query or Scan operation was performed.
>   Thus, Charlie's Query results do not reflect his PutItem operation.
>   This will be the case until DAX evicts the result set from the query
>   cache.

**Write through policy:-**

> The DAX item cache implements a write-through policy (see How DAX
>   Processes Writes). When you write an item, DAX ensures that the cached
>   item is synchronized with the item as it exists in DynamoDB. This is
>   helpful for applications that need to re-read an item immediately
>   after writing it. However, if other applications write directly to a
>   DynamoDB table, the item in the DAX item cache will no longer be in
>   sync with DynamoDB.

[DAX Consistency](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DAX.consistency.html)

In the above statement, you can consider the `other application` word as `global table` replication. The DAX wouldn't aware about the replication done for the global table.

Comment: Thanks @nationquest for your answer, what is the best architectural patterns to invalidate cache then? I can have a lambda function listening to dynamodb stream and invalidating cache in its region. is there any another option?

Comment: @nationquest this is nontrivial than I first thought, there is no api to manually invalidate a cache hence the dynamodb stream option will also not help. do you have any workaround, since TTL is not an acceptable solution.

Answer (score 3):

At this time, the DAX cache in region two will have no knowledge of the GT replicated write. Your best alternative at the moment is to keep a lower TTL on DAX in both regions, so it fetches the newest version more often.

Answer (score 0):

This has been the consistent problem with AWS service teams. They seems to design things in isolation without worrying about the different related context. I have seen this kind of inconsistency in design at several places. In fact even with in DAX and DynamoDB the 2 TTL concepts doesn’t consider its functions even though they are related. Don’t know when AWS service teams will design things with full context like Microsoft does for their solutions.